# WORDPRESS Get attachment id when publish post

Tags: wordpress, post, attachment, publish

I have a website where I upload video, wich is attach to a post. I need to add a metadata on the video (so the post attachment) but only if the is attach to the publish.
So I need to get the attach_id.

I didn't succed to have a hook in order to doing this.

I suppose is might be something like that

```
function add_post_meta_to_attachment(){
    update_post_meta($attach_id, 'is_converted', 0);
}
add_action('publish_post','add_post_meta_to_attachment');
```

But here, I really don't know how to get the attach_id of the attachment of my post

anyone help?

thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

I success in using the add_attachment hook and passing the $attahcment_ID in arg :

```
public function add_is_converted($attachment_ID){
    update_post_meta($attachment_ID, 'is_converted', 0);        
}
add_action('add_attachment', 'add_is_converted');
```